# Why is GDALWARP making straight lines in hi-res ortho imagery look sawtooth? How to Fix?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I downloaded six hi-res (6") imagery tiles from USGS. Used gdal_translate to add State Plane Coordinates (SPC) projection to the tif. Used gdal_merge to combine the six GTiffs into a single GTiff. No problems, image looks good. See subset image before.tif. [image: no sawtooth lines]

Note that pavement lane marker lines are good. Even shadows from concrete barriers are clean. Used gdalwarp to convert from SPC to UTM. In After.tif image, pavement lane marker lines have sawtooth pattern. [image: with sawtooth lines]
Sawtooth pattern more obvious when printed full page. Tried various gdal_warp options without any success to get rid of the sawtooth pattern. Has anyone had this issue and know how to refine the final image? Sample code provided.

`gdal_merge.py -o merge.tif -of GTiff -ot byte -co COMPRESS=NONE -co TILED=NO -v t1.tif t2.tif t3.tif t4.tif t5.tif t6.tif

gdalwarp -overwrite -co COMPRESS=NONE -co TILED=NO -t_srs EPSG:26918 merge.tif merge_UTM.tif`

Comment: Use cubic or bilinear resampling (the `-r` option).  Nearest-neighbor is the default which will lead to jaggedness like this

Comment: All available resampling methods are documented in https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-r. Average, lanczos and cubicspline may also work for your data.

Comment: All 5 suggested resamplings worked in getting rid of the jagged lines. Thank you @mikewatt and others.